# C#: How to return optional ref to struct

Tags: c#, return-type, ref

In C# how do I write a function that may or may not return a ref to a struct?

What I basically want is a return type `Nullable<ref OutboxSlot>` but the compiler complains about `ref` beeing an unexpected token.

I want to do is something like this:

```cs
Nullable<ref SomeFieldStruct> GetCorrectField(ref SomeStruct s) {
  // Depending on some property of s either return null or a ref to a field of s
}
```

In something like Rust I could easily declare a return type like `Option<&mut SomeFieldStruct>`.

PS: No I cannot use classes.

Comment: Did you try `ref SomeFieldStruct? GetCorrectField(ref SomeStruct s)`?

Comment: At first, you can't. Structs are value types and you want work with references (classes). You can work with unsafe structs if you want use structs references

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Isn't that equivalent to `ref Nullable<OutboxSlot>`? I need `Nullable<ref OutboxSlot>`. I need to be able to return a null/none value. How would I do that from a function with return type `ref SomeFieldStruct?`?

Comment: @Victor Can you link me some documentation of what you mean with unsafe struct references? I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In project properties, in Compilation, you must check "Allow unsafe code":

[image: Allow unsafe code]

Don't forget set in Debug and Release.

I'm going to use this structs:

```
public struct SomeStruct
{
    public int Value;
    public SomeFieldStruct Field;
}

public struct SomeFieldStruct
{
    public double Value;
}
```

Then, create your method:

```
public unsafe static SomeFieldStruct* GetCorrectField(ref SomeStruct s)
{
    // Depending on some property of s either return null or a ref to a field of s
    if (s.Value == 0)
    {
        fixed (SomeFieldStruct* field = &s.Field)
        {
            return field;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

If Value is zero, you return the address of Field property of your struct. Check it:

```
public unsafe static void Test()
{
    SomeStruct obj;
    obj.Value = 0;
    obj.Field.Value = 1.2;

    SomeFieldStruct* field = GetCorrectField(ref obj);
    if (field != null)
    {
        field->Value *= 10.0;
    }
}
```

With pointers, you must use arrow -> instead of dot. All your unsafe methods must include unsafe keyword.

Comment: Thank you for the code example. I am not quite sure what you mean with project properties, that doesn't apply to me, I guess you are using another IDE than me. I was wondering if it is possible to do this without unsafe code, since in C# you can return ref SomeFieldStruct. I was thinking about maybe returning a tuple (ref SomeFieldStruct, bool) to indicate whether the ref should be used, but then I still have the problem of needing a dummy value for the first tuple element. Do you have an idea how this could be done without unsafe?

Comment: I use Visual Studio and each project in Solution Explorer has properties (in the context menu). In that menu you can set this option. Without unsafe, C# can't return a referente of a struct by design

Comment: That is not true. In C# you can return a reference to a struct without unsafe, simply write `public ref SomeFieldStruct MyFunction(ref SomeStruct s){return ref s.field;}`.

Comment: @Adrodoc Sorry, I've been somewhat vague in my answer, I was talking in the context of this question. If you try to do that we are talking in this question you get "error CS8156: An expression cannot be used in this context because it may not be passed or returned by reference". And it's by design: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns

Comment: I guess you are right, it looks like C# does not support this without unsafe, which is quite unfortunate. I guess the fundamental problem is that C# does not have algebraic datatypes or lifetimes like Rust, which is why this problem which is easy in Rust is impossible in C# without unsafe. Thanks for the insight, I marked your anwser as accepted.

Comment: I think that unsafe is there to allow this kind of things that, as you indicate, in Rust or C++ are part of the language and in C# are not accessible. When you program at low level or need a lot of efficiency you also have to resort to unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Span` here. It has a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-span-1-ctor(-0@)) that takes just a reference and wraps it. You can than safely write code like this.

```cs
private T[] Array;
public Span<T> Get(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= Array.Length) {
        return Span<T>.Empty;
    }
    return new Span<T>(ref Array[index]);
}

var item = Get(10);
if (!item.IsEmpty) {
   DoSomething(ref item[0])
}
```

The semantics of unwrapping single argument spans aren't *great*, but you can now also declare your own `ref struct` type to wrap your reference in C#11. This also no longer needs unsafe code.

```cs
public readonly ref struct RefNullable<T> where T : struct {
    private readonly ref T _Value;
    public readonly bool HasValue => !Unsafe.IsNullRef(ref _Value);
    public ref T Value {
        get {
            if (!HasValue) { throw new InvalidOperationException(); }
            return ref _Value;
        }
    }

    public RefNullable() { }
    public RefNullable(ref T val) => _Value = ref val;
}
```

Not sure if something like `RefNullable` exists in the standard lib. I couldn't find it from my searches. `ByReference` seemed to be a thing, but I don't think that's encouraged much anymore.

I was trying to get the compiler to generate a warning/error if `Value` was called before checking `HasValue`, like `Nullable<T>` now does with Nullability checks enabled, but couldn't figure that one out. I assume `Nullable<T>` is special in the nullability checker. `[MaybeNull]` seemed to just be ignored unfortunately (presumably since the analyzer *knows* structs can never be null, and any struct that isn't `Nullable<T>` is therefore never considered nullable). If someone cracks that issue, let me know.